# where do I look for changing the excerpt from being based on characters to based on the number of words?

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts

Currently I use a paid wordpress theme and they are actually counting the characters to create the exceprt which creates unwanted characters because I use a language called Malayalam. This happens because in Malayalam there are certain characters which are represented by 2 characters from utf8.

So I am trying to change the excerpt to be based on the words which will solve the problem hopefully. Could someone point me in the right direction on where to look for it and what do I have to change?

The site is maplebooks.in

Comment: Check with your theme support if adding a "read more" tag will help. Is the theme currently just chopping the output of `the_content` to display the excerpt?

Comment: Thanks I found it out by asking the support of the theme. And it solved the issue. I reduce the number of words in the excerpt and removed the substr function which the theme was using for remove the extra characters.